# Having complete control over a launched application using the Process class

Tags: c#

I am aware of the process class and its methods/properties, as well as the ProcessInfo class (I think thats the name), which give you reasonable control over an application you launch via code, using this class.

However, if for example I launch an installer, how can I get complete control over the installer so I can click Next/Back, specify the directory, the features to install (checkboxes), and so forth?

I am guessing this may be a job for Win32 API, in which case, does a C# wrapper exist for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) for this. It's a .NET library and is fairly easy to use once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any other ways?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of from C#, no. There are products like AutoIt out there, but if you're familiar with C# then UI Automation will be much better for you.